How do I find out how to realize this logic circuit? (digital logic design course)
It's a question with multiple subquestions:
The first and second questions were to realize a 3-bit converter from gray code to binary and vice versa using at most 2 XOR gates, here are the results: (top is binary to gray, bottom is gray to binary)

Now for the question:
I'm asked to realize with 2 XOR gates and at most two 2->1 MUXs that given 3 bits and another "control" bit will convert those 3-bits from binary to gray if the control bit is 0, and from gray to binary if the control bit is 1.
I've made the following table but I still don't know how get from this table to a circuit design (C is control bit, and f() is the 3-bit output):


If you look at the two converters you drew above, what's the difference between them?  There's only one connection different between the two...what would be a good way to select one of two possible nets to connect an input to?

the only difference is the input for the bottom XOR gate. oh! I see now, I didn't think of it that way, so I don't really need the truth table, thank you very much for the explanation!

No problem!  You even have a spare multiplexer you can keep for a future problem.

is it acceptable in Stack Exchange to edit my question to include the answer and then add another question in the same vein? (the next segment of the question)
not sure as I'm kinda new here

It's better to make it a new question.  That way your original is still available in case it's useful to somebody else.  Also, you should click the check mark under the answer score to indicate that the answer solved this question.

@Nate3384 It is not only better, it is the expected way to use this site. It is not a forum. You might want to take the [tour] to learn how this site works. ;-) Never edit a solution into a question, and never change the issue in the question, please.
